# Run elisp from command line in running emacs

Tags: shell-command, server, command-line-arguments

How can I execute elisp in the currently running emacs from the command line?

The following command echoes 'hi' but doesn't set `'abc` in the emacs instance.

```
emacsclient --no-wait --eval '(message "hi") (setq abc)'
```

Is there a way to modify emacs from the command line?

My specific use case is to revert all buffers with a shell command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either wrap your two forms in a `progn`:

```
emacsclient --no-wait --eval '(progn (message "hi") (setq abc 123))'
```

Or you can send them separately:

```
emacsclient --no-wait --eval '(message "hi")' '(setq def 456)'
```

Comment: I don't think the quoting matters.  Either way, `abc` is not defined in emacs.  The goal is for `abc` to be defined in the currently open emacs.

Comment: I just tried it and both of the options listed work on my machine.  You're sure you've got the server running?

Comment: Ah, I had a zombie emacs process that was intercepting emacsclient.  It now works like a charm