# Start emacs from the command line with remote ssh file open

Tags: tramp, start-up, ssh

How to start Emacs from the command line with and open file trough ssh?

What I usually do is first open Emacs and do:
`C-X C-F /ssh:my_remote_server:/file.txt RET`

How can I directly open the file from the command line doing something similar to:

`emacs --remote "/ssh:my_remote_server:/file.txt"`

Comment: I guess this approach can help for you.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/25033/run-elisp-from-command-line-in-running-emacs

Comment: Doing `emacs -Q "/ssh:my_remote_server:/file.txt"` works fine for me. Where/how  does it break for you?

Comment: @NickD yes that work, could you do an answer with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a file when starting a new instance of Emacs you can generally do:

```
emacs "/ssh:server:file"
```

as described in `man emacs`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       emacs [ command-line switches ] [ files ... ]
```

If you use Emacs daemon and want to open a file within an existing
instance of Emacs you can do `emacsclient "/ssh:server:file"` as well
but it will cause emacsclient to block the terminal:

```
$ emacsclient "/ssh:freebsd:Makefile"
Waiting for Emacs...
```

If you want to use `emacsclient` without blocking the terminal do:

```
emacsclient --eval "(with-current-buffer  (window-buffer) (find-file \"/ssh:server:file\"))"
```

Comment: it is workin. Is there an advantage of doing this in comparison of what NickD propose in comment?

Comment: @ucsky: it works as well, see edited answer

Comment: It's the same thing: the only reason I added `-Q` was to ensure that there was nothing in any init file that would cause a problem.